# REXML::ParseException when using oauth on tumblr API v2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, heroku, tumblr

I'm using Omniauth to try and get an Oauth token from the Tumblr API v2. I am able to authorize the app at Tumblr, but when I am redirected to my app callback page I am getting this error:

```
(tumblr) Callback phase initiated.
REXML::ParseException (#<REXML::ParseException: Missing end tag for 'link' (got "head")
Line: 10
Position: 528
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
>
```

a little further down the logs I see:

```
Missing end tag for 'link' (got "head")
Line: 10
Position: 528
```

Is there some way I can debug the request object so I can see if the returned data is not formatted correctly? is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Hosting is with Heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer was in the use of outdated gems.

I was using omniauth 1.0.1 - updated to 1.1.1 and everything worked!